# Data Validation - Postal Code

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x

I have been posed the following problem:

Define a function postalValidate(S) which first checks if S represents a postal code which is valid:
first, delete all spaces;
the remainder must be of the form L#L#L# where L are letters (in either lower or upper case) and # are numbers.
If S is not a valid postal code, return the boolean False. If S is valid, return a version of the same postal code in the nice format L#L#L# where each L is capital.

Here is my code:

```
def postalValidate(S):
S = S.replace(" ", "")
   for c in range(0, 4, 2):
      if S[c].isalpha() == True:
         x = True
   for c2 in range(1, 5, 2):
      if S[c2].isdigit() == True:
         y = True
   if x == True and y == True:
            return S.upper()
   else:
      return False
```

Problem is, I get this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code has problems with indentation. Can you please [edit] the question so it has the same indentation as the code you are running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that if the condition `S[c2].isdigit() == True` is not met, the variable `y` is not assigned and so you can't check if it's True later. The easiest way to avoid it is to assign it the value of `False` in advance:

```
y = False
for c2 in range(1, 5, 2):
    if S[c2].isdigit():
       y = True
```

A couple of notes:

1. You don't need explicit `== True` in `if` clauses. `if cond` checks if `bool(cond)` is `True`, and in your case `cond` equals `True` already.
2. The result of the `range` function doesn't include its second argument:

   ```
   In [1]: list(range(0, 4, 2))
   Out[1]: [0, 2]
   ```

   You probably want to add 1 to it:

   ```
   In [2]: list(range(0, 5, 2))
   Out[2]: [0, 2, 4]
   ```

Also you can use the slice notation to avoid loops altogether.

So a couple of optimizations can reduce the length of your code:

```
def postValidate(s):
    s = s.replace(' ', '')
    if len(s) == 6 and s[0:5:2].isalpha() and s[1:6:2].isdigit():
       return s.upper()
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for being a Python noob.

Comment: Aww, I was late to the draw. This answer is better than mine. I'm deleting mine.

Comment: @Dan Nothing to apologize for. The question is stated clearly and shows some effort on your side.

Comment: One problem with your code:
Running postalValidate('n2l 3g1z') … Error: postalValidate('n2l 3g1z') has wrong type String, expected Boolean .  

I'll look into it.

Comment: @Dan I think it's expected to return `False` because the input is too long (`L#L#L#L`), but the code doesn't check for it. Neither does you version. You can add another condition to the `if`: `... and len(s) == 6`. I edited my answer

Comment: Thanks.  I'll get to fixing it, then.

Comment: I fixed it with:  
    if len(s) > 6 or len(s) < 6:
         return False .  

  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Dan You can just write `len(s) != 6`, `!=` means "not equal".